# main.INFO: Broken reference: and throws 404 error?

Tags: magento2, 404

```
[2019-04-18 09:56:18] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []
```

This is the error in exception log and system got stuck in the controller after completing its functionality rather then returning value and throws 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an **Error** but rather **Info**, Magento tells you that it can't reorder by itself elements inside `header.inner.right` on merging `xml`.

Basically the order is like this:

```
header
     |_header.inner.right
       |_user
         |_notification.messages
```

Try this :

```
<move element="user" before="-" destination="header.inner.right" />
<move element="notification.messages" after="user" destination="header.inner.right" />
```

**Edit :**

Yes, it's not an error but just info, and not because it's an `info` that you d'ont have to solve it ! The 404 error dont due from this xml order.

```
vendor/psr/log/Psr/Log/LoggerInterface.php::info(); //output : main.INFO:
vendor/psr/log/Psr/Log/LoggerInterface.php::error(); //output : main.ERROR:
```

Comment: if this is not the error then hoe can i identify the error because there is no error on front page except 404 my extension got stuck in a controller in RECURSIVE FUNCTION and stop reading code in execute method that is written after the calling of RECURSIVE FUNCTION

Comment: i am duplicating category with products when products are more then 700 it gives me this error while checking on live instance and on local this process takes time as compare to live instance but it completes the code and return the requested value on local but not on live instance unable to determine whats the problem here

Comment: You can see my edit

Comment: where should i put this code ?which file

Comment: @PЯINCƎ I have the same problem. Where to put that code please? Thank you.